# Git error message: filetype not allowed or file too large?

Tags: git

Working on an EpiServer project. I installed an EpiServer nuget package to enable Marketing a/b testing.

When I try to push to origin I get the following message:

```
remote: Control Freak: Push rejected.
remote:
remote: Control Freak
remote: -----
remote: Push rejected.
remote: Specific files [*.7z, *.bmp, *.class, *.dll, *.ear, *.exe, *.jar, *.mar, *.mfd, *.mft, *.msi, *.ocx, *.par, *.rar, *.sar, *.tar, *.tar.gz, *.tgz, *.war, *.zip] larger than 0 bytes are not permitted.
remote: The following file is too large:
remote:
remote:   Project/Project.Site/modules/_protected/EPiServer.Marketing.Testing/EPiServer.Marketing.Testing.zip (177755 bytes)
remote:
To https://tasktrack.telekom.at/bitbucket/scm/ma/a1-digital-episerver-backend.git
 ! [remote rejected] develop -> develop (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://me@tasktrack.website.com/bitbucket/scm/ma/project-episerver-backend.git'
```

The nuget package zip is 172 KB in size.

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory: the repository you're trying to push to won't allow `.zip` files.

Comment: In most cases, you don't want to check in the prohibited kinds of files anyway.  Your repository should not contain dependencies; those should be managed with a dependency tool and possibly an artifact server.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty obvious that your Git admin people have configured [Control Freak](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1217635/control-freak-for-bitbucket-server?hosting=server&tab=overview) to not allow certain files at all (by only allowing those with size zero). Zip files are, by the looks of that message, one of the file types disallowed.

> `Specific files [*.7z, *.bmp, *.class, *.dll, *.ear, *.exe, *.jar, *.mar, *.mfd, *.mft, *.msi, *.ocx, *.par, *.rar, *.sar, *.tar, *.tar.gz, *.tgz, *.war, *.zip] larger than 0 bytes are not permitted.`

You need to talk to them about relaxing this restriction if you really need Zip files placed in the repo.